# Add small change in two branches - git

Tags: git

I have two branches one master and other release branch. release branch is taken from master few days ago and has changes that are specific to release. master branch is used for active development.

Now i made one change in master branch. How should i copy this one change to release branch. Master branch has commits done by other team members too.

Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use [cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) command to apply commit from one branch to another in the following way:

1. Find the hash of commit you wish to apply;
2. `git checkout release-branch`
3. `git cherry-pick <commit-hash>`

After that, I would suggest you to merge `release-branch` back to `master` to avoid conflicts in the future.

Comment: The simplest way is to copy changes from master to release branch and both branches will be equal no merging required.

Comment: The question author tells `copy this one change to release branch`, so that other changes from `master` should not be applied.

Answer (score -1):

```
 git checkout release-branch
 git fetch origin
 git rebase origin/master
```

then `push` the release branch.

```
git push release-branch
```

Comment: if you want to be carefull and alter commits you can also use interactive rebasing. Learn more about how to do one of those on under the "Interactive Rebasing Section" https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing

Comment: this would bring all unstable stuff from master to the release branch